# python - copy header lines and modify file using csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to modify a tab-delimited file in the following format

```
Channel Text File
Prj unnamed
Author  [Unknown]
JobMode Grid
XCells  512
YCells  384
[...]
4,041000;4,041000;4,041000  90,000000;90,000000;90,000000   Aluminum    11  225
Phase   X   Y   Bands   Error   Euler1  Euler2  Euler3  MAD BC  BS
0   0.0000  0.0000  0   3   0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0   255
0   0.5000  0.0000  0   3   0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0   255
0   0.9999  0.0000  0   3   0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0   255
[...]
1   110.49  43.997  12  0   119.81  43.402  254.14  1.0830  199 255
1   110.99  43.997  12  0   119.41  43.282  254.29  1.2132  187 255
1   111.49  43.997  11  0   119.76  43.065  253.84  0.9688  184 255
1   111.99  43.997  12  0   119.69  42.989  253.87  1.0751  189 255
[...]
```

I hope to find the maximum value of *X*, modify *X* based on *Xmax* as well as change *Euler1* by 180 in each line and write all data including the header lines to a new file. I searched and find out that csv module is appropiate for this purpose. So, what I did is

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

headerLines = 15

with open("input", "r") as inf:
  with open('output', 'w') as outf:
    inReader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t')
    outWriter = csv.writer(outf, delimiter="\t") 
    Xmax = max(float(row[1]) for row in islice(inReader, headerLines, None))

    for i,row in enumerate(inReader):
      if i < headerLines:
        outWriter.writerow(row)
      else:
        row[1] = str(float(row[1])*(-1)+Xmax)  
        row[5] = str(float(row[5])-180)
        outWriter.writerow(row)
```

My problem is that no data are written to the outfile file when searching for *Xmax*. However, everything seems to work fine when deleting the search for *Xmax* as if this line deactivates *outWriter.writerow()*. Can anybody tell me, where's the mistake?
Of course, using pandas could be an alternative but I'd like to know understand why my code using csv isn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `islice(inReader, ...)` you consume all the data in `inReader` without saving it anywhere.  You need to store the data in a variable, and only then find the max.

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

headerLines = 15

# you can put both context managers in a single "with"
with open("input.csv", "r") as inf, open('output', 'w') as outf:
    inReader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t')
    outWriter = csv.writer(outf, delimiter="\t")

    inLines = list(inReader)
    Xmax = max(float(row[1]) for row in islice(inLines, headerLines, None))

    for i,row in enumerate(inLines):
      # refactor to avoid code duplication
      if i >= headerLines:
        row[1] = str(float(row[1])*(-1)+Xmax)  
        row[5] = str(float(row[5])-180)
      outWriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! However, your code results in an empty outfile too. Can you guess why?

Comment: Edited the answer; I fixed a couple of minor bugs. With (my adaptation of) the sample data you posted, it works for me. I had to guess a bit since you elided some of the headers.